# Why am I finding so few items in the wasteland?

Tags: fallout-shelter

I have one vault dweller who does all the exploring, and he usually finds a ridiculous amount of items. Recently, I've sent him out for eleven and twenty hours, and he only finds three items. He has a relatively high Luck (8) and his other stats are pretty good, too.

[image: Exploring Wasteland 11h 42m, Three Items Collected]

Comment: Luck of the draw.  Item finding is random and you could have just hit a bad patch of random numbers.

Comment: There's advantage of this situation, i.e. your dweller can go further without having auto-return after getting their 100th item from the wasteland --provided they endure the wasteland. Instead of looking to get as many item as possible, I've been looking for a way to get as least item (rare or legendary only, hopefully) as possible during exploration.

Comment: Isn't perception more important for finding items? Doesn't the text explicitly say so?

Answer (score 1):

I would have to agree with @Nelson above -- I think this is just bag RNG luck. I've had several instances where the same level 50 guy goes out and finds tons of stuff, and others where he finds almost nothing. IMO the only recourse is to drastically increase your sample size and send the same guy out lots more times and see what happens. If it's 100% nothing after many attempts, I'd start to think it's a bug, otherwise, blame the RNG.